# Using WordPress Core Functions In An External Cron File

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have a cron setup to sort through some orders and perform other various functions throughout the day. If there's any issues I should be sent an email via a function that uses wp_mail.

At the very beginning of the cron file I thought I loaded the WP functions correctly with:

```
require_once( '../../wp-load.php' );
```

The cron file has no problem executing other functions found in WordPress's functions.php file, so I'm confused as to why wp_mail does not work from within the cron file.

**UPDATE:** I've given up on using this function and switched to PHP's mail() function.

Comment: You didn't explain the problem you're seeing. Is wp_mail just not sending an email, or instead is it saying there's no such function as wp_mail?

Comment: @GregBurkett No email is sent - "confused as to why wp_mail does not work from within the cron file."